# Comparing string value and splitting them

Tags: c#, string

I have a set of strings that have multiple values. How to split and compare them.

```
I want to buy your 5 Apple for 2 Dollars.
I want to buy your 23 Oranges for 32 Quarters.
```

The parts I want to grab are:

```
I want to buy your x(int) Obj(string) for y(int) Currency(string)
```

I want to single out the object and currency, then compare them to a list of allowed items.

The int can be 1-3 digits.

The way I thought about doing is trying to split from after "your ", then split from " for ", then split the int and string apart.

Is there a better way?

Edit:
The currency could have multiple words separated by space "Canadian Dollars" etc.

Comment: Is the dot at the end (`.`) supposed to be part of the `Currency`?

Comment: Regular Expressions.

Comment: you could split on the space and take elements 5,6 and 8,9 of the array.

Comment: @user1672994 You're missing capture groups, but that's basically how I would do it.

Comment: That correct @DavidG - Even I did not like what  I posted. That's why I deleted it :).

Comment: `RegEx` is unnecessary, @CharlesMay makes the best suggestion, assuming your string inputs are consistently formed.

Comment: @Rafalon no it's just a period at the end of the string

Comment: Can the strings be multiple words?

Comment: @CharlesMay Ah I see that seems good ty but my currency could be multiple words with space in them

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, it might be, let me edit my question

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ What happens if the currency is something like `British Pounds`? That's where RegEx would be much simpler.

Comment: and if the last two could have more elements, a simple count of the elements should allow you to determine if you need to re-combine some of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex solution would be something like this:

```
var regex = @"I want to buy your (\d{1,3}) (.+?) for (\d{1,3}) (.+?)\.";
var match = Regex.Match("I want to buy your 5 Apples for 3 Dollars.", regex);
var number1 = match.Groups[1];
var string1 = match.Groups[2];
var number2 = match.Groups[3];
var currency = match.Groups[4];
```

Explanation:

- `\d{1,3}` matches between 1 to 3 digits.

  - `.+?` will keep matching everything until what comes after it matches.
  - `()` captures the substrings into groups. The stuff the brackets capture can be accessed by `Groups[1]`, `Groups[2]`, etc.

Here's a non-regex solution:

```
var str = "I want to buy your 5 Apples for 3 Dollars.";
var words = str.Split(' ');
var number1 = words[5];
var string1 = words[6];
var number2 = words[8];
var currency = new string[words.Length - 8];
Array.Copy(words, 9, currency, 0, currency.Length);
var currencyString = string.Join(" ", currency);
```

Comment: Ahhh great! I looked into regex but it was a little confusing before because it just looked like a bunch of random characters. Understood now, thank you!